# How to compare results from multiple streams and return highest result

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm writing a Pokergame in Java and I have troubles writing the hand evaluate. I was thinking about writing a function which returns the number of cards with the same suit to check for flushes first.
I have a class Card with an enum SUITS and a getter getSuit.
In my Evaluator i want a method `countSuits()` which returns an int value with the highest amount of matching suits in the hand. 
I could check for each Suit seperately like this:

```
Arrays.stream(cards).filter(card -> card.getSuit()== Card.Suit.DIAMOND).count();
```

and then compare the return values and return the highest, but I would like to find a solution to do this with one stream.

Is this even possible? I'm still a little struggling to understand streams...

Comment: Or maybe it would be even better, if the method would return a true if there are 5 matching suits in the hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupingBy` to group by suits and then using `counting` as a downstream find the count of cards for each suit in your list:

```
 Map<Suit, Long> collect = cards.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getSuit, Collectors.counting()));
```

See java doc for [**`groupingBy()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [**`counting()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--)

To make sure if there are 5 suits in the hand you could check:

```
if (collect.values().contains(5L)) {...}
```